# Telethon как отправить файл вместе с текстом?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Нужно отправить через telethon одним сообщением и видео и текст, такое возможно?

Answer (score 0):

```py
client.send_file(channel_id, file, caption='test')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]